# Run a script within a script? - Hive (and other QL's)

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hue

Is it possible to call a script and run it before running the rest of a script?

My goal is to perform a set-up script which will download and organize the data necessary to perform my main query.

I am looking for something like:

```
create table logcontent (content string) row format delimited fields terminated by '\n';

**call secondary hive script with date-range arguments and download necessary logs into <logcontent>**

**perform the rest of the query**
```

I want to do this in order to create a nice abstraction for the table setup so that the end-user does't have to worry about table set-up, it will be done for them.

I know that AWS has the option to add a Hive script as a step in the job but how can I do the same thing locally? Is this possible? If so, what is the syntax? If not, what are some work-arounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to organize your main shell script in a similar template as below.

```
## Content of main.sh

## Code block to setup Hadoop Environment and config in Path, if not already exist.

## Step 1> Create the hive table in non-interactive mode.
hive -e "create table test(id int, name string) row format delimited fields terminated by '\n'"
# Check if the command is successful. IF else logic can be added.
echo $? 

## Step 2> Call the secondary script executable to download logs
ksh downloadlogs.sh # Assuming the download script could be invoked this way.

## Step 3> Execute rest of the hive queries to organize data
hive -e "select * from test"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, instead of running a bash script, would it be possible to run a hive script? Would I just replace `kph` with `hive`?

Comment: Yes. with syntax like `hive –f /home/user/sample.sql` you can run a hive script. PS: if you like the answer you may consider to accept. :)

Comment: Yup, will accept now that you have clarified that. That was what I was looking for. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
create table logcontent (content string) row format delimited fields terminated by '\n'; 
&& sh /path/to/script.sh 
&& **perform the rest of the query**
```

The `&&` symbol is to execute the subsequent command after the former command finishes successfully.

Comment: Sorry I think i worded my question poorly, but would the `sh /path/to/script.sh` still work if I call a hive script? Would I have to replace `sh` with `hive`?

Comment: You could execute hive queries by using `hive -e "select * from tblname;"`. Add this line in shell script and it will execute. But you cannot use hive to execute shell script like this `hive /path/to/script.sh`. This wont work.

Comment: Well I mean if I do, `hive /path/to/script.hql`. Would this work? My thinking is that this is similar to what one would do with bash scripts.